# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported

Tags: identityserver4

Following the example of creating an identity server from the identityserver4 documents, I received the following exception on the line AddDeveloperSigningCredentials()

```
  System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
  HResult=0x80090029
  Message=The requested operation is not supported.
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.ExportKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle 
   key, String format)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat format)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.ExportParameters(Boolean includePrivateParameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsCrypto.CreateRsaSecurityKey()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsCrypto.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(IIdentityServerBuilder builder, Boolean persistKey, String filename)
   at WH_Identity.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Stage\WH_Identity\WH_Identity\Startup.cs:line 18
```

More info:

The above is thrown when using identityserver4 in web project targeting .net framework 4.6.1

When the same is done using .NET core 2, it works and creates a tempkey.rsa file in the root.

Anyone have any idea on how to resolve this or any work around?

-----------------Edit 1/11/2018--------------------

Alright, so I went into the identityserver4 source and obtained the following code and ran it in Linqpad with same results. Google search doesn't give much information on this. Hoping someone knows what I am doing wrong.

```
void Main()
{
    var key = CreateRsaSecurityKey();

    RSAParameters parameters;

    if (key.Rsa != null)
        parameters = key.Rsa.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);
    else
        parameters = key.Parameters;

    parameters.Dump();
    key.Dump();

}

public static RsaSecurityKey CreateRsaSecurityKey()
{
    var rsa = RSA.Create();
    RsaSecurityKey key;

        if (rsa is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
        {
            rsa.Dispose();
            var cng = new RSACng(2048);

            var parameters = cng.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);
            key = new RsaSecurityKey(parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            rsa.KeySize = 2048;
            key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
        }


    key.KeyId = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(16);
    return key;
}
```

The error is on the line
 `var parameters = cng.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);` 
Is it OS version or something related to framework?

Comment: Lets first clarify one thing - why do you want to use ids4 in a project targeting .net framework 4.6.1? Than the workaround. No knowing your big picture, is not helping others to help you.

Comment: We already have a lot code/projects in .net framework for authentication/user mgmnt etc. My aim is to transfer those to work with identityserver to provide SSO. Those in turn have their own dependencies on older dlls. So my best bet is to get this to work in .net framework.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you setup IdentityServer4 with .NET core 2 as a single project and replace the 'old' security in your apps with IdentityServer3 packages that can interact with the IdentityServer?

Comment: Identity server 4 only works with .Net core i think that @RuardvanElburg solution is going to be the best way forward.

Comment: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/01/15/platforms-where-you-can-run-identityserver4/

- the above link from the author confirms that it can be used on .net framework 4.5 and above

Comment: I think there is some confusion. You cannot use Ids4 in a .Net 4.5 project. It has to be a .net core 2.0 project, but it may target net45. See the comment from your link: Dominick Baier says: July 17, 2017 at 16:50 "IdentityServer4 is asp.net core only".

Comment: IdentityServer4 runs on ASP.NET Core 2 - which in turn is compatible with .NET Core 2+ and .NET Framework 4.6.1. We have tests for the above code on 4.6.+1 - and they are working fine.

Comment: So to sum everything up - as @leastprivilege sais (after all he is one of the guys that has written IDS) IdentityServer4 runs **only** as an ASP.NET Core 2 project, but this **doesn't** mean that you can't target it (as authentication provider) from projects, that run on .Net Framework. Just think about it - there are lots of JS projects examples, that target IdentityServer4. Are they running on .NET Core 2? :)

Comment: Is that so? You can create Asp.Net Core 2.0 project targeting .net framework 4.6.1, which is what I am doing and I think that is what @leastprivilege is talking about.

Comment: For now I have generated an X509 Certificate and am using the .AddSigningCredential(X509Certificate2) extension to go ahead with my development. Atleast this seems to be working fine with .net framework at the moment.

Comment: There is a bug tracker for samples. You may want to report it there if you think it is a bug.